# How do I try/catch an object creation in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, constructor, destructor

I'm running my program in [catchsegv](http://man.he.net/man1/catchsegv) and it shows `boost::archive::text_oarchive` destructor running just before my program segfaults:

```
Backtrace:
??:?(_ZN5boost7archive28basic_streambuf_locale_saverIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev)[0x50c678]
??:?(_ZN5boost7archive21basic_text_oprimitiveISoED1Ev)[0x50c833]
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:97(_ZN5boost7archive18text_oarchive_implINS0_13text_oarchiveEED2Ev)[0x417baf]
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:114(_ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveD2Ev)[0x416645]
...
```

I'm not sure why the `boost::archive::text_oarchive` destructor is running, as far as I can tell the object isn't finished with. So my guess is that an exception has been thrown and that's why the destructor is running..?

I have this code:

```
std::stringstream ss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive outArchive(ss);
outArchive << *instPtr;
```

The `catchsegv` output shows the `text_oarchive` destructor is called on the middle line, my program never reaches the third line.

So what I want to do is wrap the `outArchive` construction in a try/catch block. I tried like this:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive outArchive;
try {
  boost::archive::text_oarchive outArchiveTemp(ss);
  outArchive = outArchiveTemp;
}
catch ( std::exception& ex ) {
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Error creating text_oarchive...";
  exit( 1 );
}
```

But that doesn't work because there is no default constructor for outArchive on the first line. I'm afraid I don't understand C++ well enough to do what I want to do, which is basically to try/catch object creation in order to diagnose why the `outArchive` destructor is running and my code segfaulting... help?

Comment: "But that doesn't work." - what happens?

Comment: Run it in a debugger. With gdb, the command you're looking for is 'catch throw', to make it break whenever an exception is thrown.

Comment: Hey jalf. I ran in gdb with 'catch throw'. The exception got notified like this: Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), 0x00007ffff7b2fdbd in __cxa_throw ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: Hey M.M. I think there are a number of reasons why the code I tried doesn't work. The first one being that there is no default constructor for outArchive on the first line (I updated my question concerning that). I think there might be further reasons that I don't quite understand...

Comment: @JohnElliotV If there's no default constructor, your code won't compile.

Comment: @JohnElliotV yep? So now you're at the point where the exception is thrown. Then you debug the problem.

Comment: @jalf, yep, the exception is boost::archive::archive_exception "output stream error" -- just trying to figure out why that happens... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a pointer to the outarchive, instead, and initialize it in the try block (just for the sake of understanding the cause of the exception. Assign it to a smart pointer in your actual production code if you need to keep using a pointer even after you've understood the cause of the exception. See for instance [std::aut_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) or [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if you want to do that).

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive *outArchive;
try {
  outArchive = new boost::archive::text_oarchive(ss);
}
catch ( std::exception& ex ) {
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Error creating text_oarchive..."<<ex;
  exit( 1 );
}
```

Comment: Ah, use a pointer... thanks! That's surfaced my issue. I'll create a different question for that.

Answer (score 1):

This line does not make sense:

> The catchsegv output shows the text_oarchive destructor is called on the middle line, my program never reaches the third line.

It's not possible that the text_oarchive destructor to be called for this line:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive outArchive(ss);
```

So, likely, you're being fooled by the tool you are using which links to this line *by default of not having any other line to link to*.
This happens because the destructor is implicit and as such does not have any source code line to refer to.

*As a side note, you could pipe the output of your tool with `c++filt` to get C++ demangled names (much easier to read) like this:*

```
catchsigv [your args here] 2>&1 | c++filt
```

Actually, if you have a segmentation fault, it's mean that somewhere in your code, a memory access was done unexpected (like writing to a null pointer or out of the allocated area, etc...)

When you spot the error, either it's too late, either it's not.

For example for out of bound access, it's usually too late, the error *might* be spot by the allocator (new/delete/malloc/free/etc) **after** the next call to the allocator.

When dealing with a null pointer (reading/writing/accessing) then it's *usually* not too late, the segmentation fault signal (`SIGSEGV`) is sent immediately.

In the former case, you could use Valgrind that'll tell you when you've done out of bound access.

In the later case, you should run your program under the debugger (gdb/lldb/etc...), the debugger will stop at the exact position where the signal was raised. Check the local variables around (and `this`) for null value being used.

Please also notice that a segmentation fault **does not** get caught by a `try`/`catch` block, so there is no point trying to do so, it'll not work.